# Mongoose searching on array subdocument ObjectId not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is honestly driving me crazy. Here's the problem:

I'm running the following query in Mongoose:

```
s.findSubdocument=function(uid, cb)
{
     this.model('User').find({"flwng._id":uid.toString()}).select('flwng').exec(cb);
}
```

on the following User Schema:

```
var userSchema= new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        uname:{type:String, index:{sparse:true, unique:true, dropDups:true}}, //the username
        email:String,
        pwd:{type:String},
        flwng:[{_id : {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId},uname : String}], //_id of users I am following
        flwrsz:Number,
        flwngsz:Number,
        feedsz:Number,
    }, {j: 1});//j:1 means guarantee it is written to the journal.

userSchema.set('autoIndex', true);
userSchema.index({"fid":1}, {sparse:true, unique:true, dropDups:true});
userSchema.index({"flwng._id" : 1});
```

Where uid="53c4f16c431247694f0000a3" ==> but I get an empty array back :(

When I run the same exact query in the mongo shell:

```
db.users.find({"flwng._id":"53c4f16c431247694f0000a3"});
```

I get the right set of results back. I tried with and without an index and schema on "flwng._id", I tried to drop the index, reIndex and I'm now running out of ideas. Am I doing something wrong with Mongoose?

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!
Henri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mismatch between your existing documents in mongodb and your schema. Your data has records where `flwng._id` is a String, which is why you get results in the mongo shell. But your mongoose schema defines that as an `ObjectId`, so when you query with mongoose, mongoose casts your string value to an `ObjectId` and the query doesn't match. Either write a migration to fix your existing data or update your schema to match your data in terms of String vs ObjectId data type and things should start working through mongoose.

Comment: You're correct! I changed flwng to flwng:Array and now it returns the correct set of results. What strategy do you recommend to convert existing Strings to ObjectID? I tried and had no luck with looping through the results and casting the value as such:

    users[i].flwng[j]._id=new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(sUid);
    users[i].save()

Comment: Got it to work! Thanks Peter. For those running into a similar problem, I got String -> ObjectId migration to work with the following query in Mongoose: this.model('User').update({"flwng._id":uid.toString()}, {"flwng.$._id":uid},{multi:true} ).exec(cb);